# Check if contact is online in node-xmpp

Tags: ejabberd, node-xmpp

Maybe someone has examples of code? I can't find anything about it.
Jabber server - **ejabberd**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a client, you know a contact is online when:
- he authorized your account to see his presence,
- AND you receive his presence in your client.

Consequence: You have to track the presence of your contact on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for ejabberd xmpp server.
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd maybe this is what you want!